# return filename and file creation date after grep

Tags: find

I am using below to retrieve certain files based on content and filename:

```sh
find /labels/ -type f -iname '*.*' -exec grep -l 'MB2306' {} +
```

Now I also need to know the creation date of the returned files. What do I need to change here to achieve that?

find is running on 4.6.0 on Red Hat Enterprise 8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With recent versions (4.9 or newer for `-files0-from`) of GNU `find` and GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
find /labels/ -type f -name '*.*' -exec grep -Zl MB2306 {} + |
  find -files0-from - -prune -printf '%TFT%TT%Tz %p\n'
```

With other `find` implementations or older versions of GNU `find` and if you also have GNU `xargs` and GNU `stat` available:

```
find /labels/ -type f -name '*.*' -exec grep -Zl MB2306 {} + |
  xargs -r0 stat -c '%y %n' --
```

`%T` (`%y` for `stat`) is for the last modification time, which can also be seen as the creation time of the *contents* of those files. You can replace with `%B` (`%w` for GNU `stat`) for the file's birth time, but that is not available on all systems and file systems and is not often a useful metric depending on what exactly you're after.

Note that `-name '*.*'` (`-iname` doesn't make much sense as there's no letter in that pattern) is to report files whose name is made entirely of text and contains at least one `.`. Note that it also matches on a file called `.bashrc` for instance. If you wanted to match on files that have an extension, whether the file name is made of text or not, you'd want `LC_ALL=C find ... -name '?*.*'`¹. If you wanted any file regardless of their name, you'd just omit those `-name pattern`.

The zsh shell has most of `find`'s features available in its globs which support recursion and filtering by file type and has a `stat` builtin (since 1997, predates GNU `stat`), so in that shell, that can be done with:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat -nLF %FT%T.%N%z +mtime ${(0)"$(
  grep -lZ MB2306 /labels/**/?*.*(ND.))"}
```

(still assuming GNU `grep` or compatible for its `-Z` option and here not restricting to text-only file names).

The `%FT%T.%N%z` `strftime()` specification (extended with `%N` for nanoseconds here) or GNU `find`'s `-printf` equivalent `%TFT%TT%Tz` give you a standard non-ambiguous `2023-06-14T10:23:05.047789132+0100`-like format. You can adapt to your preference, see `man strftime` for details of the format.

GNU `stat`'s format is `2023-06-14 10:23:05.047789132 +0100` and is not customisable, though you can also use `%Y` for `1686734585` and `%.Y` for `1686734585.047789132`.

---

<sup>¹ that `LC_ALL=C` would also affect `grep` and how it interprets the contents of files, but as you're looking for a fixed string here, that shouldn't make any different and if anything would likely even speed things up.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command `AND`'s all predicates (unless you use the `-o` predicate) so you could append `ls -l --time=creation` (which your OS should support, I verified on Alma 9.1), and get a list of creation times of matching files:

```
find /labels/ -type f -iname '*.*' -exec grep -q 'MB2306' {} \; -exec ls -l --time=creation {} \;`
```

I changed `grep` to `-q` since you only need to know whether or the file matches: If it does, the `ls` runs; if it doesn't, the `ls` doesn't run.

Comment: It is actually -time=ctime here and when running your command I get the error

`grep: unrecognised option '--time=ctime'`

Running just

`ls -l --time=ctime`

works fine

Comment: @MaxB, `ctime` is the change status time, not *creation* time.